# C++ Updating a data member using a struct pointer

Tags: c++, struct

I have what should be an easy question. I have a global function (setData) which takes a pointer to my test struct. When I try to update the data member it is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test {
    int data;
};

void setData(test* tp, int newData) {
    test t = *tp;    // I think the problem is here.
    t.data = newData;
}

void printData(test* tp) {
    test testStruct = *tp;
    cout << testStruct.data;
}

int main()
{
    test ts;
    ts.data = 22;
    setData(&ts, 44);
    printData(&ts);
}
```

Comment: Don't just say "not working".  Describe what, specifically, is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `test t = *tp; // I think the problem is here.`

Yes, you are right! Your code is making a copy, modifies it, and then promptly discards.

You should instead modify the structure passed in through a pointer:

```
tp -> data = newData;
```

Note the `->` operator. It is the pointer equivalent of the `.` member access operator. It is equivalent to

```
(*tp).data = newData;
```

but it looks nicer.

You can do the same thing in the `printData`, although it is merely an inefficiency there:

```
cout << tp -> data;
```

Answer (score 1):

what you did in `setData` is creating a new struct, and changed the data there.
what you want to do is this:

```
void setData(test* tp, int newData) {
    tp->data = newData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test t = *tp;
```

Copies your object before the affectation. Thus, the modification is lost.
You need to access the pointed object:

```
tp->data = newData;
```

I suggest you read a bit more about pointers and structures in general before diving further in C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
test t = *tp;    // I think the problem is here
```

Yep.  You've now made a local copy and modified that.  Instead, you should just use:

```
tp->data = newdata;
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
void setData(test* tp, int newData) {
    test t = *tp;    // I think the problem is here.
    t.data = newData;
}
```

`setData` declares its own copy of a `test`. If you want to tweak the caller's `test`, you must do it through a pointer or a reference:

```
void setData(test* tp, int newData) {
    t->data = newData;
}
```

or

```
void setData(test* tp, int newData) {
    test &t = *tp;    // I think the problem is here.
    t.data = newData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `setData()` function is only modifying the local *copy* of your `struct`.

You need to copy it back:

```
void setData(test* tp, int newData) {
    test t = *tp;
    t.data = newData;
    *tp = t;
}
```

Or modify the global directly:

```
void setData(test* tp, int newData) {
    tp->data = newData;
}
```

The latter version is slightly more efficient and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You're only modifying the local variable. Do this instead

```
tp->data = newData;
```